# ngx-admin NbDummyAuthStrategy redirection after login

Tags: angular, nebular, ngx-admin

I've been building an interface using Nebular's NbAuthModule and NbDummyAuthStrategy. I have found that when using NbPasswordAuthStrategy you can easily set a redirect on successful login, however when using NbDummyAuthStrategy it doesn't accept a redirect on a "successful" login. Nothing in the nebular documentation appears helpful in this regard.

Is there any way to redirect after login when using the NbDummyAuthStrategy?

```
NbDummyAuthStrategy.setup({
      name: "dummy",
      alwaysFail: false,
      token: {
        class: NbAuthSimpleToken,
      },

      \\ below doesn't work
      login: {
        redirect: {
          success: "/pages/dashboard",
          failure: "null, // stay on the same page
        },
      }
    }),
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the NbPasswordAuthStrategy or simply add the

```
redirect:{ success:'your-value',failure:'your-value'},
```

in the dummy-strategy-options.d.ts file

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried to extend the dummy-strategy-options both with your suggestion, as well as taking the same interface declaration from the password-strategy-options.d.ts file and inserting it into dummy-strategy-options. Neither worked after some experimentation, so I ended up using NbPasswordAuthStrategy with AlwaysFail: false set. This works well enough for demonstration purposes :)